# IPC communication between 2 processes with Perl

Tags: perl, ipc

Let's say we have a 'Child' and 'Parent' process defined and subroutines

```
my $pid = fork;
die "fork failed: $!" unless defined($pid);

local $SIG{USR1} = sub {
kill KILL => $pid;
$SIG{USR1} = 'IGNORE';
kill USR1 => $$;
};
```

and we divide them, is it possible to do the following?

```
if($pid == 0){
    sub1();
#switch to Parent process to execute sub4()
    sub2();
#switch to Parent process to execute sub5()
    sub3();
}
else
{
    sub4();
#send message to child process so it executes sub2
    sub5();
#send message to child process so it executes sub3
}
```

If yes, can you point how, or where can I look for the solution? Maybe a short example would suffice. :)

Thank you.

Comment: [perlipc](http://p3rl.org/perlipc)

Comment: Why do you want to have two processes if you're going to make it so only one is executing at time?

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole page in the docs about inter process communication: [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

To answer your question - yes, there is a way to do what you want. The problem is, exactly what it is ... depends on your use case. I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish - what you you mean by 'switch to parent' for example?

But generally the simplest (in my opinion) is using pipes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
pipe ( my $reader, my $writer ); 
my $pid = fork(); #you should probably test for undef for fork failure. 
if ( $pid == 0 ) { 
    ## in child:
    close ( $writer );
    while ( my $line = <$reader> ) {
        print "Child got $line\n";
    }
}
else {
    ##in parent:
    close ( $reader );
    print {$writer} "Parent says hello!\n";
    sleep 5;
}
```

Note: you may want to check your `fork` return codes - `0` means we're in the child - a number means we're in the parent, and `undef` means the fork failed.

Also: Your pipe will buffer - this might trip you over in some cases. It'll run to the end just fine, but you may not get IO when you think you should.

You can open pipes the other way around - for child->parent comms. Be slightly cautious when you multi-fork though, because an active pipe is inherited by *every* child of the fork - but it's not a broadcast.